# What's the best way to get the current operating system?

Tags: nim-lang

I'm looking for something similar to python's sys.platform, which returns 'linux', 'windows', etc, or even better, something like python's platform module which gives you the operating system, distribution, release version, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
when defined windows:
  echo "I'm on Windows!"
elif defined linux:
  echo "I'm on Linux!"
else:
  echo "I'm on some other platform!"

when defined x86:
  echo "x86 specific code!"
elif defined amd64:
  echo "amd64 specific code!"
else:
  echo "generic code!"

when (NimMajor,NimMinor,NimPatch) > (0,10,2):
  echo "Such a modern Nim version!"

echo "OS: ", hostOS, ", CPU: ", hostCPU, ", cpuEndian: ", cpuEndian, ", NimVersion: ", NimVersion
```

This prints on my system:

```
I'm on Linux!
amd64 specific code!
Such a modern Nim version!
OS: linux, CPU: amd64, cpuEndian: littleEndian, NimVersion: 0.10.3
```

Comment: I'm beginning with Nim, new commenting at Stack too, and have been looking for this answer, works great. Thanks!

Just a curiosity, my laptop it's a Macbook with M1. I have two terminals to run in native mode, arm64 and other in i386 mode. When run your code from both terminals always shows the same result:

>>I'm on some other platform!
>>amd64 specific code!
>>Such a modern Nim version!
>>OS: macosx, CPU: amd64, cpuEndian: littleEndian, NimVersion: 1.4.4

Do you know if there is any specific variable other than hostCPU?